# Setting vimwiki_list in a lua.init file

Tags: vim, lua, neovim

I am using neovim and am trying to use lua for my settings.
I have installed vimwiki and following the instructions to set

```
let g:vimwiki_list = [{'path': '~/vimwiki/',
                      \ 'syntax': 'markdown', 'ext': '.md'}]
```

I have tried doing this in lua with

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_var('vimwiki_list', {path = "~/mywiki/"})
```

This results in the error

```
Error detected while processing function vimwiki#vars#init[2]..<SNR>31_populate_wikilocal_options:
line   49:
E714: List required
Error detected while processing function <SNR>30_vimwiki_get_known_extensions:
line    3:
E727: Start past end
E714: List required
Error detected while processing /home/me/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/vimwiki/plugin/vimwiki.vim:
line  303:
E714: List required
line  315:
E712: Argument of map() must be a List or Dictionary
E714: List required
Error detected while processing function <SNR>30_build_menu:
line    2:
E727: Start past end
E714: List required
```

How do I correctly set these type of options, specifically for vimwiki, and more generally for other cases?

Answer (score 4):

I did;

```lua
vim.g.vimwiki_list = {{path = '~/Docs/Mywiki', syntax = 'markdown', ext = '.md'}}
```

which resolved the error and set the options

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for *exactly* this, and I'm certain it would have cost me an hour or so to finger-mumble my way to a solution.

Comment: It's unrelated to the OP's question, but... in case it helps the next person, Lua doesn't like keys that start with a period, so you might need something like this if you choose to use Markdown with VimWiki:
`vim.g.vimwiki_ext2syntax = {['.md'] = 'markdown', ['.markdown'] = 'markdown', ['.mdown'] = 'markdown'}`